# issue with pagebeforeshow back and going to next page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

am using pagebeforeshow to a page to getjson data and going back from that page displaying the same page again and again and after again clicking on back going to before page, same with going to next page from that particular page. any suggestion please thanks.

code is as follows,

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#pagethree', function(e) {
        //alert("inpGrid");
        var i = 0;
        var url = "http://192.168.0.101:8080/iConfig/html5_XV/slideDemo/json/listinp.json";
             // var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&callback=?" ;
              $.getJSON(url, function(res) {
                  console.log(res)
                  var attr = "";
                   $.each(res.response.output.records, function(i, v) {
                                  $.each(res.response.output.fieldInfo, function(index, value) {

                                        if (index == 0 && offset==v[value["label"]]) {
                                            attr =1;
                                        }
                                        if(attr == 1){
                                            if(index == 0){
                                                document.getElementById('inpName').value = v[value["label"]];
                                                inpName = v[value["label"]];
                                            }
                                            if(index == 1){
                                                document.getElementById('inpAlias').value = v[value["label"]];
                                                inpAlias = v[value["label"]];
                                            }
                                            if(index == 2){
                                                document.getElementById('inpDataType').value = v[value["label"]];
                                                inpDataType = v[value["label"]];
                                            }
                                            if(index == 3){
                                                document.getElementById('inpDefault').value = v[value["label"]];
                                                inpDefault = v[value["label"]];
                                            }
                                            if(index == 4){
                                                document.getElementById('inpVisible').value = v[value["label"]];
                                                inpVisible = v[value["label"]];
                                                attr = "";
                                            }
                                        }
                                  });
                 });

            });
});
```

and pagethree.html looks like

```
<html>
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="pagethree" data-close-btn="none">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Selected Input</h1>
  </div>


  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="height:300px;" >
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                         <label for="name">Name:</label>
                         <input type="text" name="inpName" id="inpName"   disabled="disabled"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                     <label for="name">Alias:</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="inpAlias" id="inpAlias"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                                 <label for="name">Data Type:</label>
                                                 <input type="text" name="inpDataType" id="inpDataType"   disabled="disabled"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                                 <label for="name">Default Value:</label>
                                                 <a href="listDefault.html"  data-transition="slide"><input type="text" name="inpDefault" id="inpDefault"  /></a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="name">Visibility:</label>
                                <select name="inpVisible" id="inpVisible">
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                </select>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
         </div>
         <a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="save1" data-inline="true" data-rel="back">back</a>

    <a href="slidingdialogs.html">Go to Page One</a>

  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text in Dialog</h1>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using 'off' first. $(document).off('pagebeforeshow').on('pagebeforeshow', '#pagethree', function(e) {

Comment: not working, it is as before only.

Comment: ihave used bind instead of on but still it is same.

Comment: can someone answer to this please.